# Exporting unique items from CrawlSpider

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy's `CrawlSpider` spider class to iterate over the list of `start_urls` and crawl each site's internal pages to fetch e-mail addresses. I would like to export a file with a single (unique) item for each start_url, with the list of matched e-mails. For that I purpose I needed to override the `make_requests_from_url` and `parse` methods so I can pass each start_url item in the response's meta dict (see code) to the internal pages. The output from running this code is:

```
www.a.com,['webmaster@a.com']
www.a.com,['webmaster@a.com','info@a.com']
www.a.com,['webmaster@a.com','info@a.com','admin@a.com']
```

However, I only want the export file to contain the last entry from the above output

`(www.a.com,['admin@a.com,webmaster@a.com, info@a.com'])`

Is that possible?

**Code:**

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    start_urls = [... urls list ...]

    def parse(self, response):
        for request_or_item in CrawlSpider.parse(self, response):
            if isinstance(request_or_item, Request):
                request_or_item.meta.update(dict(url_item=response.meta['url_item']))
            yield request_or_item

    def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
        # Create a unique item for each url. Append email to this item from internal pages
        url_item = MyItem()
        url_item["url"] = url
        url_item["emais"] = []

        return Request(url, dont_filter=True, meta = {'url_item': url_item})

    def parse_page(self, response):
        url_item = response.meta["url_item"]
        url_item["emails"].append(** some regex of emails from the response object **)
        return url_item
```

Comment: What about dump the message when spider closing ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pipeline` to process items.

see [Duplicates filter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter) on Scrapy documentation.